# React Native - out of memory

Tags: performance, react-native, out-of-memory, react-navigation

I'm developing a react native application. I have just realized that the application memory usage is growing, even when I'm not touching the app. If I navigate between screens I see that memory usage is growing much faster.

I have got some memory snapshots in Safari web inspector but I do not know how to use this information.

Can you please give me some hints? I have found out that this may be some react native navigation issue.

Versions:

"react-native": "0.59.9",
"react-navigation": "^3.11.1",

Memory usage chart

[image]

Memeory snapshot comaprison

[image]

Comment: It seems like there's a recursive function call that doesn't get suspended.